# Drawing in Java using Canvas

Tags: java, swing, graphics, canvas, awt

I want to draw in Java's Canvas but can't get it work because I don't know what I'm doing.  Here's my simple code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frmMain = new JFrame();
        frmMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmMain.setSize(400, 400);

        Canvas cnvs = new Canvas();
        cnvs.setSize(400, 400);

        frmMain.add(cnvs);
        frmMain.setVisible(true);

        Graphics g = cnvs.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        g.drawString("Hello", 200, 200);
    }
}
```

Nothing appears on the window.

Am I wrong to think that Canvas is a paper and Graphics is my Pencil? Is that how it works?

Comment: are you just trying to draw graphics?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Don't use Canvas as you shouldn't mix AWT with Swing components unnecessarily.
- Instead use a JPanel or JComponent.
- Don't get your Graphics object by calling `getGraphics()` on a component as the Graphics object obtained will be transient.
- Draw in the JPanel's `paintComponent()` method.
- All this is well explained in several tutorials that are easily found. Why not read them first before trying to guess at this stuff?

---

Key tutorial links:

- Basic Tutorial: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- More advanced information: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: Thanks! I did search the web. Yes they can be found easily, but cannot be understood easily.

Comment: Wish I could give upvote to each point, but seems like not to use Canvas for Swing at the first place holds a major weight.

Comment: Good points. But keep in mind people will find your answer also when searching for this subject. That's why I think you should include links to the tutorials you mentioned.

Comment: You get an upvote on the strength of *I want to draw in Java's Canvas but can't get it work because I don't know what I'm doing.* alone.

Answer (score 7):

You've got to override your Canvas's `paint(Graphics g)` method and perform your drawing there. See [the paint() documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

As it states, the default operation is to clear the canvas, so your call to the canvas' graphics object doesn't perform as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Why would the first way not work. Canvas object is created and the size is set and the grahpics are set. I always find this strange. Also if a class extends JComponent you can override the

```
paintComponent(){
  super...
}
```

and then shouldn't you be able to create and instance of the class inside of another class and then just call  `NewlycreateinstanceOfAnyClass.repaint();`

I have tried this approach for some game programming I have been working and it doesn't seem to work the way I think that it should be.

Doug Hauf

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String title = "Test Window";
    final int width = 1200;
    final int height = width / 16 * 9;

    //Creating the frame.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //Creating the canvas.
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    canvas.setSize(width, height);
    canvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.setVisible(true);
    canvas.setFocusable(false);


    //Putting it all together.
    frame.add(canvas);

    canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);

    boolean running = true;

    BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    Graphics graphics;

    while (running) {
        bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        graphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

        graphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        graphics.drawString("This is some text placed in the top left corner.", 5, 15);

        bufferStrategy.show();
        graphics.dispose();
    }
}
```